# Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM/GeoAlchemy2 results to a dictionary and ultimately JSON

Tags: python, json, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask/SQLAlchemy to create a web app with a map in it, so naturally I'm using a PostGIS database.  The geom column requires an ST_Transform and somehow I need to turn this column and all others into JSON.  The general structure of the database is:

```
from app import login, db
from datetime import datetime
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from time import time
from flask import current_app
from sqlalchemy import func

class Streets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = db.Column(db.String(50))
    geom = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='LINESTRING'))

    def to_dict(self):
        data = {
            'id': self.id,
            'street': self.street,
            '_geom': func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(self.geom, 4326))
        }
    return data
```

My api route turns this result into an api:

`return jsonify(Streets.query.get_or_404(id).to_dict())`

But I keep getting this error: `NameError: name 'ST_AsGeoJSON' is not defined`

I also tried to create my `_geom` value like this:

```
    data['_geom'] = db.session.query(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(self.geom, 4326)))
```

The error message is: `TypeError: Object of type 'BaseQuery' is not JSON serializable`

Finally, I tried an api route like this:

```
    data = Streets.to_dict(
        db.session.query(
            func.ST_AsGeoJSON(
                func.ST_Transform(
                    Streets.geom, 4326
                )
            )
        )
        .filter(Streets.id==id))

    return jsonify(data)
```

And I get a different error:
`AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'id'`

If I run this in `flask shell` it works:

```
streets = db.session.query(
        Streets.id,
        Streets.street,
        func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(Streets.geom, 4326)))
```

How can I perform `ST_Transform` and get JSON to my api route?

***UPDATE***

I found this in the SQLALchemy documentation that got me some progress: "orm.column_property() can be used to map a SQL expression".  So I tried adding this to my `class Streets(db.Model)`:

```
coords = db.column_property(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(geom, 4326)))
```

Then I add it to `data` like this:

```
def to_dict(self):
    data = {
        'id': self.id,
        'street': self.street,
        'coords': self.coords
        }
    return data
```

But now I'm double encoding my results, once into GeoJSON and then I `jsonify` it:

```
return jsonify(Streets.query.get_or_404(id).to_dict())
```

So my api inserts `\`'s:

```
{"coords": "{\"type\":\"MultiLineString\",\"coordinates\":[[[-80.8357132798193,35.2260689001034],[-80.8347602582754,35.2252424284259]]]}"}
```

And using `ST_AsText` just turns it into text:

```
{"coords": "MULTILINESTRING((-80.8357132798193 35.2260689001034,-80.8347602582754 35.2252424284259))"}
```

I think I'm close with this update, but does anyone have a suggestion for getting correct GeoJSON with the JSON of the other fields of my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error

```
NameError: name 'ST_AsGeoJSON' is not defined
```

means that your example code is not what you were actually using. You had forgot to access it through `func`. It would not work after fixing that either, since you'd be mixing the SQL world and the Python world. `func.ST_AsGeoJSON(...)` creates an SQL function expression object that is supposed to be compiled to SQL and sent to the DB in a query, not passed to `jsonify()`.

The second error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'BaseQuery' is not JSON serializable
```

should be somewhat obvious.

```
data['_geom'] = db.session.query(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(self.geom, 4326)))
```

creates a `Query`, and a too broad query at that, since you've not limited it to fetch data of the current object. The `Query` object is not JSON serializable.

In

```
data = Streets.to_dict(db.session.query(...)...)
```

you pass the `Query` object as `self` to `Streets.to_dict()`, which then tries to access its `id` attribute in

```
'id': self.id,
```

which fails for obvious reasons – namely passing an unrelated object as the instance to a method.

The `column_property()` approach produces the doubly encoded JSON because SQLAlchemy does not by default expect `ST_AsGeoJSON` to return JSON and treats it as text instead, which it actually returns. Try decoding in between manually:

```
def to_dict(self):
    data = {
        'id': self.id,
        'street': self.street,
        'coords': json.loads(self.coords)
        }
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am converting the SQL alchemy result with Geometric data to JSON in Fast API (should be similar to Flask)

```
# ORM model of Police station
class PoliceStation(ORMbase):
    __tablename__ = 'police_station'

    id:    int = Column(Integer,    primary_key=True)
    name:  str = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    # Geometric data
    location  = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT',        srid=4326), nullable=False)
    boundary  = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326), nullable=False)


# Pydantic model for Police station
class Schema:
    class PoliceStation(BaseModel):
        id:                 int
        name:               str
        location:           Optional[PointModel]        # from pydantic-geojson
        boundary:           Optional[MultiPolygonModel] # from pydantic-geojson


# List police stations
@route_division.get("/police_station",
                    tags=["Police Station"],
                    response_model=List[Schema.PoliceStation])
def police_station_list(id: int = Query(None),
                        name: str = Query(None, max_length=64),
                        include_location: bool = Query(None),
                        include_boundary: bool = Query(None),
                        order_by: Ordering = Query(None),
                        limit: int = Query(le=1000, default=500)):
    try:
        session = sessionMaker()            
        columns = [PoliceStation.id, PoliceStation.name]
        if include_location:
            columns.append(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(PoliceStation.location).label('location'))
        if include_boundary:
            columns.append(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(PoliceStation.boundary).label('boundary'))
        query = session.query(*columns)
        
        if id is not None:
            query = query.filter(PoliceStation.id == id)
        if name is not None:
            query = query.filter(PoliceStation.name.ilike(f'%{name}%'))
        if order_by == Ordering.DESC:
            query = query.order_by(PoliceStation.id.desc())
        else:
            query = query.order_by(PoliceStation.id.asc())
        
        policeStations: List[PoliceStation] = query.limit(limit)
        return [
            Schema.PoliceStation(id=policeStation.id,
                                 name = policeStation.name, 
                                 location = loads(policeStation.location) if include_location else None,
                                 boundary = loads(policeStation.boundary) if include_boundary else None)
            for policeStation in policeStations
        ]
    except Exception as e:
        handleException(e)
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Comment: `location = loads(policeStation.location)` - where does the `loads` method come from here?

Comment: @EmilStyrke `from json import loads` - import the loads from json library